# Test-ServiceHealth output display

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am running `Test-ServiceHealth` on my Exchange servers

```
$ServiceHealth = Test-ServiceHealth -Server $S.Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServicesNotRunning
```

I needed to send the output from the `ServicesNotRunning` value to a HTML email report. The problem I face is that the values returned are in the below format,

```
MSExchangeSA MSExchangeAB MSExchangeIMAP4
```

But for the purpose of the report I needed them to be in a tabular format.

```
MSExchangeSA 
MSExchangeAB 
MSExchangeIMAP4
```

I tried using the -Split or -Replace but not helping. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a line break you could simply do this:

```
$ServiceHealth -join "`r`n"
```

Comment: thanks! That worked...another way I found was to put a ForEach loop for each element of the ServiceHealth o/p and place that in the table with a line break